# The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This page was working fine,show records from directly services with no error. but now it gives the above error.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="odsUsers"
                                    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Width="100%">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">
 <ItemTemplate>

<%#((System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry)Container.DataItem).Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value%>

   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
/Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Project builds successfully but when I open the page then it gives error

Comment: When you're opening the page, is this on the same machine that you're building the project?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices` assembly to your project??

Comment: @marc_s: Yes System.DirectoryServices assembly is already added.I also remove this and added again but same error.and one more this error also other machine(not talking about development server).this page was working fine from last many days.I added some library projects in solution,one is window service

Comment: @mservidio: Yes I am on same machine where I build project

Comment: When I remove the above code from aspx page for testing purpose and add below line in page load event and it gives no error."System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry();"

Comment: System.DirectoryServices shows in intellisense in cs page but not in aspx page.Other classes appears in intellisense successfully in aspx but System.DirectoryServices

Answer (score 43):

After you add your directory services reference, right click on the `reference` and go to `properties`.  Set `"CopyLocal"` to true.

Comment: If you happen to not see your folder 'references' search on the top of the "solution explorer" panel for a 'show all files' option.

Answer (score 20):

I'm pretty sure that I'm "publishing" my application from my development box to my IIS box completely incorrectly.  However, I found this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e052fc9-6c23-42f2-9a8d-afe52c63596b/cant-use-systemdirectoryservicesprotocols-namespace-help), and it worked for me.

If you are using web application then in your web.config add the following code.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 14):

1 - Right-Click Mouse Button on "References"
2 - Click "Add Reference ..."
3 - Click "Browse" Button
4 - Find the following files in folder:

> "C:\Program Files\Reference\Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1"
>
> -System.DirectoryServices.dll
>   -System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll

5 - Select them
6 - Press "OK" Button

Comment: Nowadays you can just pick from the list, instead of browsing.

Comment: 2020 this still works, although the directory has changed to: `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\*version*`

Answer (score 3):

The easy way that worked for me was to right-click on References => Add Reference, and select System.DirectoryServices (and needed subassemblies).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue in Visual Studio 2015 with an MVC project that was targeted for .NET Framework 4.5.2.  Changing the target framework to .NET 4.5 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an import directive on your asp.net page.  Make sure it is fully qualified.  Make sure you have a reference to the assembly in your project as well.

```
 <%@ Assembly Name="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0,
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a reference (in your project) to [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx). Since you're using it in what looks like an aspx markup page, sometimes the compiler will let those fly during "build" but fail when you actually execute the page.

Comment: System.DirectoryServices assembly is already added,I removed this and added again but same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I did a search for DirectoryServices.dll in my windows folder.  Since all the versions that came up had the same size, I picked one and copied it to the bin folder in my website.  If you don't have a bin folder, just create it.
Once I did that, I was able to open my webpage without errors.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if assembly "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" is added in the references. Adding System.DirectoryServices will not work.